# Wordpress Blog/Author name not showing up

Tags: wordpress

I am using a customized theme and there is a line of code like this in for example single.php.

```
     <p class="postmetadata"><?php _e('Posted by','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_author_meta('namefl'); ?> <?php _e('on','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_time('n/d/y'); ?> &bull; <?php _e('Categorized as','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_category(',') ?></p>
```

The call to wordpress function the_author_meta('namefl') doesn't return anything, thus the author name is blank;; display something like was posted by on 11/12/11 for example.

All I would like to do is to display the author name in there.  I am using WP 3.2.1.  What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with the Wordpress codex as well as http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. That site is better at answering codex questions. SO is for programming questions.

Read this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/

Use this to solve your problem (has to be used inside the loop)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I looked at the codex now along with other info provided and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parameter for the_author_meta($field, $userID). It looks like you have $userId, but you are missing the first parameter.

The first paramter, $field, should be one of the following, depending which field you want exactly:

- user_login
- user_pass
- user_nicename
- user_email
- user_url
- user_registered
- user_activation_key
- user_status
- display_name
- nickname
- first_name
- last_name
- description
- jabber
- aim
- yim
- user_level
- user_firstname
- user_lastname
- user_description
- rich_editing
- comment_shortcuts
- admin_color
- plugins_per_page
- plugins_last_view
- ID

So what you may want instead could be

```
<p class="postmetadata">
    <?php _e('Posted by','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_author_meta('display_name', 'namefl'); ?> <?php _e('on','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_time('n/d/y'); ?> " <?php _e('Categorized as','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_category(',') ?>
</p>
```

or if you're looking for the current post's author within "The Loop"

```
<p class="postmetadata">
    <?php _e('Posted by','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?> <?php _e('on','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_time('n/d/y'); ?> " <?php _e('Categorized as','Mimbo'); ?> <?php the_category(',') ?>
</p>
```

For more information, please look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta).

Comment: Thanks, in my case only the one parameter is needed, 'display_name'.  I just don't know what the theme author was doing with 'namefl'.  By changing 'namefl' to 'display_name' that fixed it.